# Pages of same website opened in multiple instance of browser should refer to same variable using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

1. I have website www.xyz.com and it is having 3 pages a, b and c.
2. I open one page a in Internet Explorer instance 1 (i.e. www.xyz.com/a )
3. I open the page b in new IE window instacne 2 (i.e. www.xyz.com/b )
4. I open the page c in the new tab of IE window instance 3(i.e. www.xyz.com/c)

I need a method using javascript **ONLY**, via which I will be able to refer to a variable which I have defined for the website xyz and all three pages a,b and c will use the same variable. If the variable does not exsist I should be able to create the variable using **javascript**.

Comment: Your only chance is using cookies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of options, but the most-supported is [cookies](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html). When you open the first page you can set a cookie, which will then be available on all subsequent pages on the site.

Another option for modern browsers (IE 8+, Chrome, Firefox, etc) is to use `localStorage` which works similarly to cookies, but the data is kept client side and never accessible to server-side scripts. Saves a bit of overhead if the data is more than a few bytes.

Answer (score 0):

Variables at client-side can be managed in different ways:

1. Hidden form fields, or `<input type='hidden' id='variable-name' name='variable-name' value='some-value' />`, which are scoped to one page, that is, one HTTP Request, and Response. So this option is not applicable for you.
2. Parameters sent in URL, known as Query String, which are also scoped to one URL, that is, one HTTP Request and response. So, this options is not applicable either.
3. Using server-side session objects, to share a variable between many pages, which is widespread and applicable, but of course not in your case, where you want to work with JavaScript.
4. Using **Cookies**, which is shared among all pages, of a specified domain and path. For example, a cookie set for `www.xyz.com` and for the path `/`, can be accessed from all the pages like `www.xyz.com/a`, `www.xyz.com/b`, and `www.xyz.com/c`.

So, as others have mentioned, your only solution is to use **cookies**.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript variables across multiple pages of a same domain can be accessed using cookies:

See here for more details: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp